# Unable to read params property from query string?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple app that access the opentable api (http://opentable.herokuapp.com/api/restaurants). My app, when loaded, simply displays content specified from the query parameters. For example, appending `?city=toronto` would give me all restaurants in Toronto. Here is a working, hardcoded example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Spinner from "./components/common/Spinner";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoading: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // // let city = this.props.match.params.city;
    // // console.log(city);
    // console.log(this.props.match.params.city);
    fetch("http://opentable.herokuapp.com/api/restaurants?city=Toronto")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: true,
          items: json
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    const { isLoading, items } = this.state;
    let itemsToArray = Object.values(items);
    return !isLoading ? (
      <div>
        <Spinner />
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          {itemsToArray[3].map(item => (
            <div>
              <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
            </div>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

If I were to uncomment `console.log(this.props.match.params.city);`, it tosses an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`. Am I accessing the params incorrectly? I'd like to do something like,

```
componentDidMount() {
  let city = this.props.match.params.city;
  fetch(`http://opentable.herokuapp.com/api/restaurants?city=${city}`)
    .then(...
```

Comment: It's not, this is a very minimal demo. I purposefully left out router, Im thinking of using something like `window.location.href` and parse the params from there

Comment: That's what I explained in my answer. Kindly have a look at it.

Comment: What's the current value of `this.props.match`? Is a string or a URL object?

Comment: @MikeK Check out **https://92wn8l61wo.codesandbox.io/?city=Toronto**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use something like:

```
http://myapp/page?city=Toronto
```

Then, `this.props.match.params.city` won't work. The reason being, the use-case of `match.params.city` is supposed to be in the Routes.

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

<Route path="/path/:city" component={App} />
```

In your `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method, try using:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let city = urlParams.get('city');
```

For the above code, have a look at [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115) In your code, if you try logging the value of `city`, it might be `undefined` if you haven't configured your route this way.

**Sample Code**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    city: "None"
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    let city = urlParams.get("city");
    this.setState({
      city
    });
    console.log(city);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <h3>You are in {this.state.city}!</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Working Demo:** [CodeSandbox](https://92wn8l61wo.codesandbox.io/?city=Toronto)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to access the URL params

```
var getParams = function (url) {   
    var params = {};
    var parser = document.createElement('a');
    parser.href = url;
    var query = parser.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    if(vars == ''){
        params = '';
        return params;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        params[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
    return params;
};
```

and call it

```
console.log(getParams(window.location.href));
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to wrap your `App` Class component with `withRouter`? so, it will look like the following:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Spinner from "./components/common/Spinner";

class App extends Component {
  //....
}

export default withRouter(App);
```